# How to get Latitude and Longitude from Django Location PointField

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, postgis

Please how do i get the latitude and longitude from Django Location PointField, as i need it pass it to React native. This is what i mean, when i log my location, this is what i get
`"location": "SRID=4326;POINT (4.570313 7.013668)",`

and its obviously the lat and long that is there. But i need to extra it from the logged out. I dont know how to go about it please.

Or is there a better way to have get location into django, and extra it for the frontend with reactnative?

Answer (score 1):

A `PointField` will wrap a [**`Point`** object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#point). You can get its values through subscripting:

```
location[0]  # 4.570313
location[1]  # 7.013668
```

Comment: Okay. Thanks alot. I remember you, You have helped me alot... Another thing. when i console.log(location.data)... I get this `SRID=4326;POINT (4.570313 7.013668)` I have tried to go past `SRID` not working.

Comment: Because when i try `location[0]` i get just #S

Comment: @NelsonKehinde: but you will need to do this at the backend, so Django should "unpack" the point in variables, and then construct for a example a dictionary or list, and send that to the frontend.

Comment: @NelsonKehinde: at the fronend yes, since there it is just a simple string. At the backend it is still a `Point` object.

Comment: Okay. True. Thanks lot